# Network connectivity issues with Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, windows-store

I have my Windows 8 Pro build 9200 installed on my Dell laptop. I want to install some new apps and updates from the Store but there might be some network problem that caused the downloading gauge showing up but not really running at all.

I followed some instructions that switched from local user to my Microsoft account, but this "Please wait" screen keeps showing and I don't really know why.

I still have internet access and can use some apps like People, Mail, etc. with my account logged in, I can surf the net using Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

I did another test using `cmd` with

```
ping -t google.com
```

and it showed that my laptop has internet access.

Anybody knows a solution to make the Store working properly? Or is there any workaround to switch to the Microsoft account instead of a local user account?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Windows Firewall is enabled and firewall service is running when trying to connect to Windows Store. Having firewall enabled is a requirement to connect to Windows Store.

Comment: I have my fire wall activated allowing Outbound connection and Inbound connection. Nothing has changed so far...

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I have disabled proxy

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that my ccleaner/registry booster deleted essential files that caused the problem. I reinstalled Windows and remove those programs and everything now working just fine ;)